# Random HTML Encoding Appearing, can't find where it coming from

Tags: html, encoding

Working on a site that someone else created and I just reformatted the files. For some reason this odd Encoding appears, "ï»¿ ", and I can't figure out why. I think I narrowed it down to one part of the code, but even then I can't be sure. Also, this only happens on some pages and others it does not... Weird!

Here is an image:
[image: Weird ACS LL encoding]

It always appears at the top of that page in every page that has it. Here it the codes for that file.

This is the template code:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="slider"><?php include 'modules/slider.php'; ?></div>
    <div class="main"><?php include 'includes/'.$content; ?></div>
</div>
```

This is the file handler code:

```
<?php
$title = 'Academics';
$content = 'academics.php';
$meta = 'Academics';
include 'template/template.php';
?>
```

This is the file where the information is stored.

```
<?php
$title = 'OLP Academics';
echo '
<div id ="content">
 <h2>Academics at Our Lady of Peace School</h2>
        <p>The academic program at OLP recognizes that all children learn  differently based on their age, learning style, and God-given ability. At OLP we assess a child\'s readiness and skill development and target  their instruction to their learning stage, providing continuity in  learning and continuous progress. Course content in the elementary  grades is presented repeatedly over the years with increasing depth and  mastery expected as the child matures in skill level. This gives  students the chance to be secure in basic skills. We offer accelerated  math and literature classes to qualified 6th-8th grades. Parents and  students should be aware that additional time may be needed to complete  homework in advanced classes.</p>
          <p>OLP curriculum requirements are determined by the Diocese of  Charleston\'s Department of Education. Specific skills and knowledge are  outlined for each grade level in the following subjects: Mathematics,  Language Arts, Social Studies, Science, and Religion. Students also  receive instruction in technology, art, music, physical education,  library skills, and Spanish. Instruction in these courses is 45 minutes  per week. Students in 7th and 8th grades receive an additional 45  minutes of Spanish weekly. These areas are often correlated with the  core curriculum and strengthen the child\'s total development. For more  detailed information, see the OLP Student Handbook.
               </div>
';

?>
```

I narrowed it down to at least this line where it starts at in the template code:

```
<div class="main"><?php include 'includes/'.$content; ?></div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Save your files with UTF8 without B.O.M. That is an issue with mixed encodings, and one of the files is saved as UTF8.

Comment: That looks like a byte order mark. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark In your editor, you should be able to change the encoding to UTF8 without BOM.

Comment: @Tobias It is a Byte order mark. This has been asked before. This issue happened to me before. The solution is to use another encoding or save without B.O.M.

Comment: Just did that, works wonders! Now it just gonna suck cause I don't think Notepad++ has a mass file edit in this way...
@IsmaelMiguel put it as the answer so I can check it off.

Comment: @Matt There isn't enough content to answer. You can answer it and I'll make sure that it gets upvoted. Sadly, there isn't an option for that on Notepad++.